# how to convert this part of code from assembly to C language

Tags: c, assembly, pic, microchip

i have a problem converting assembly code for microchip pic into C language
it is two parts
first part is

```
movlw HIGH RevTable ; get MS byte of table
```

and the table is

```
RevTable
        retlw B’00000000’ ; invalid
        retlw B’00100001’ ; phase /6
        retlw B’00000110’ ; phase /4
        retlw B’00100100’ ; phase /5
        retlw B’00011000’ ; phase /2
        retlw B’00001001’ ; phase /1
        retlw B’00010010’ ; phase /3
        retlw B’00000000’ ; invalid
```

so what does that mean? i can not understand it

the second question is

```
incfsz ADC,w ; if ADC is 0xFF we’re at full speed - skip timer add
```

how it could be in the C
thanks a lot

Comment: Can we C your `C` code so far

Comment: for the second question the assembly is
Loop
call ReadADC ; get the speed control from the ADC
incfsz ADC,w ; if ADC is 0xFF we’re at full speed - skip timer add
goto PWM ; add Timer0 to ADC for PWM 
movf DriveWord,w ; force on condition
goto Drive ; continue

and the C is
void main (void)
{
    char ADCReading;
    Initialize();
    Commutate();            //determine present motor position
    ADCReading = ReadADC(); //get the speed control from the ADC
    if(ADCReading == )
}

Comment: for the first question
Commutate
movlw SensorMask ; retain only the sensor bits
andwf SensorPort,w ; get sensor data
xorwf LastSensor,w ; test if motion sensed
btfsc STATUS,Z ; zero if no change
return ; no change - back to the PWM loop
xorwf LastSensor,f ; replace last sensor data with current
btfss DirectionBit ; test direction bit
goto FwdCom ; bit is zero - do forward commutation
; reverse commutation
movlw HIGH RevTable ; get MS byte of table
movwf PCLATH ; prepare for computed GOTO
movlw LOW RevTable ; get LS byte of table
goto Com2

Comment: and the C is
void Commutate (void)
{
    char result;
    result = (SensorPort&SensorMask);
    if((result^LastSensor) != 0)
    {
        LastSensor = result;
        if (DirectionBit == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
}

Comment: The first part can be simply done using a switch/case statement. The second is simply adding one to ADC and checking if it reached 255 using an if/else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code sample is insufficient so I can't tell you all about:

```
movlw HIGH RevTable ; get MS byte of table
```

This is only a part of computed table jump.
Your asm code must look something like:

```
movlw HIGH RevTable
movwf PCLATH            ;set high byte RevTable address
movf  TableIndex, w
movwf PCL               ;set low byte RevTable address this is computed table jump
;The return value is in wreg so one from RevTable table depend of TableIndex value
```

In c something like:

```
char RevTable[] = {'0','6','4','5','2','1','3','0'};

char TableIndex = 1;
char ValueFromTable;

ValueFromTable = RevTable[TableIndex] ;
```

The second part of code:

```
incfsz ADC,w ; if ADC is 0xFF we’re at full speed - skip timer add
```

Here is missing the second asm instruction which is executed or not depend of ADC value, something like:

```
 if (ADC != 255) ...
```